# access class variable within a class being instantiated in class that has the variable

Tags: php

take this example:

```
class Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = array('a' => 'b');
        $this->child = new Child();
    }

    public function calling()
    {
        $this->config['b'] = 'b';
        $this->child->answering();
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function answering()
    {
        return $this->config['b'];
    }
}
```

p.s. I know returning `$this->config['b']` won't work, but I didn't know how to return what I wanted so I inserted that as a filler.

how can I instantiate the `Child` class into the `Parent` class and somehow access the parent variable `config` inside of the child class.

Comment: Well, you can't. Because the object instances do not share data. You also should not instantiate child classes from parent classes, you're turning inheritance in its head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function?

```
class Child
{
   public function foo(&$config) {
      // do stuff with $config
   }
}

class Parent
{
   public function bar() {
      $Child = new Child();
      $Child->foo($this->config);
      echo $this->config; // config should change to whatever Child last set it too

   }
}
```

Comment: how would this work if the config variable is changed later down the code?

Comment: if child changes value, parent's instance variable should also be? Is that what you want?

Comment: if parent changes the value of the variable will the updated be accessible thru the child?

Comment: @Eli You really don't seem to be understanding OOP and inheritance very well. Take a step back and tell us what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I understand OOP concept, what I am experimenting with here is how to share a config variable across multiple classes without creating a singleton and sharing data like that. I'm just trying to expand my experience in different coding styles.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
class Parent {

    protected function getConfig( $key ){ 
        if ( isset( $this->config[ $key ] ){
            return $this->config[ $key ]; 
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {


    public function answering(){
        return $this->getConfig('b');
    }

}
```

Comment: And how would this help? `Child` inherits the *method*, but not the *instance data*.